# In Keras, how to get 3D input and 3D output for LSTM layers

Tags: keras, lstm

In my original setting, I got

```
X1 = (1200,40,1)
y1 = (1200,10)
```

Then, I work perfectly with my codes:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(40, 1), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add((Dense(10)))
```

Now, I further got another time series data same sizes as `X1` and `y1`. i.e.,

```
X2 = (1200,40,1)
y2 = (1200,40)
```

Now, I stack `X1`, `X2` and `y1`, `y2` as 3D arrays:

```
X_stack = (1200,40,2)
y_stack = (1200,40,2)
```

Then, I try to modify my `keras` code like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(40, 2), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(12, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add((Dense((10,2))))
```

I want my code work directly with the 3D arrays `X_stack` and `y_stack` without reshaping them as 2D arrays. Would you give me a hand on how to modify the settings? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add another dimension to represent the number of time steps.

From Keras documentation on [recurrent layers](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/):

> if return_sequences: 3D tensor with shape  (batch_size, timesteps,
>   units).

Something like this:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_shape=(40, 10, 3), return_sequences=True))
```